# XCode 6.2 UIKit.h Foundation.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode

I have recently updated version to xCode6.2 and previous one I was using xCode6.2 beta.
It works fine with all previous versions and xCode6.2 beta as well.

When I am update it's version, I have removed xCode beta completely and install new one. But it is getting this issue, and I have added UIKit, Foundation to libraries. No luck yet.

The thing what I have tried and suspicious additionally;

- Check framework search path at build settings(nothing mentioning that)
- Other LD Flags in build settings.
  This is suspicious, because it's have keys -frameworks Foundation, -frameworks UIKit

Have not enough understandings about other LD flags this values, so tried to remove them, but nothing new.

When I open other project with new version of xCode, they are all working fine but just that project.

Can anybody help this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a few hrs, I found the solution.

The error was because of the some path specified in OTHER_LD_FLAGS and OTHER_C_FLAGS have not changed.

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk

It was like this but it should be iPhoneOS8.2.sdk according to the changes of xCode version

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to simply uninstall xcode completely with appCleaner or such. And reinstall it.

I suspect it will work and you will save time otherwise spent searching for a solution.